# Retrieve parameter from a Jenkins REST query

Tags: jenkins

The following REST query will return parameters of the last successful build of a job:
https://localhost/job/test1/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json 
I'd be interested to retrieve one of the parameters of this build, the BUILD_VERSION:

```
{

    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "actions": [
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.CauseAction",
            "causes": [
                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.Cause$UpstreamCause",
                    "shortDescription": "Started by upstream project \"continuous-testing-pipeline-for-nightly\" build number 114",
                    "upstreamBuild": 114,
                    "upstreamProject": "continuous-testing-pipeline-for-nightly",
                    "upstreamUrl": "job/continuous-testing-pipeline-for-nightly/"
                }
            ]
        },
        { },
        {
            "_class": "hudson.model.ParametersAction",
            "parameters": [

                {
                    "_class": "hudson.model.StringParameterValue",
                    "name": "BUILD_VERSION",
                    "value": "1.1.15"
```

Is there a way to retrieve the BUILD_VERSION (1.1.15) directly using the REST Api or do I have to parse manually the json string ?
Thanks

Comment: Well I've tried appending the parameter as query parameter or path parameter and it didn't work. As you are downgrading my question I suppose the answer should be obvious. Would you be so kind to provide it ?

Comment: Try XML variant with XPATH something like this: `.../lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?xpath=//action[@_class='hudson.model.ParametersAction']/parameter[(@_class='hudson.model.StringParameterValue') and (./name='BUILD_VERSION')]/value`

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: No.

Easiest way to programmatically access any attribute exposed via the JSON API is to take the JSON from one of Jenkins supported JSON APIs (in your case: `https://localhost/job/<jobname>/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/json`)

1. Copy the resultant JSON into http://json2csharp.com
2. Generate the corresponding C# code.  Don't forget to create a meaningful name for top level class.
3. Call RestAPI programmatically from C# using [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp/).
4. Deserialise the json to the C# class you defined in 2 above.

Wammo, you have access to the entire object tree and all its values.

I used this approach to write an MVC5 ASP.NET site I called "BuildDashboard" to provide all the information a development team could want and answered every question they had.

Comment: This will be useful only if you need all the data from Jenkins, but if you just need a single value, why go through all this trouble :)

Comment: Cause its quick, easy, reliable and programmatic and works if you need just one value or all of it.  Cutting and pasting code generated by json2csharp.com mean the number of keystrokes effort is virtually unchanged. JSON is better than XML

Comment: But your entire answer is built around C#, what  about the people who use JAVA or Python or any other language how would this benefit them ?? you can except them to write a separate program just to read the value let alone a single value ??

Comment: Deserialising json emitted by Jenkins is the best approach.  I know how to do it in C#.  Java will have similar tools to do the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah you can get the value,But it will only work for XML API :(
The JSON API will return a simplified json object using Tree :)

So Jenkins provides you with api (XML,JSON,PYTHON) from which you can read the Jenkins related data of any project. Documentation in detail is provide in https://localhost/job/test1/lastSuccessfulBuild/api

In that it clearly states that

1. **XML API** - Use XPath to control the fragment you want.For example, ../api/xml?xpath=/*/*[0]
2. **JSON API** - Use tree
3. **Python API** - Use st.literal_eval(urllib.urlopen("...").read())

All the above can be used to get a specific fragment/piece from the entire messy data that you get from the API.

In your case, we will use tree for obvious reasons :)

**Syntax :** `tree=keyname[field1,field2,subkeyname[subfield1]]`

In order to retrieve BUILD_VERSION i.e. value

```
//jenkins/job/myjob/../api/json?tree=lastSuccessfulBuild[parameters[value]]
```

The above should get you what you want, but a bit of trail and error is required :)

You can also refer here for a better understanding of how to use Tree in JSON API
https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/taming-jenkins-json-api-depth-and-tree

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with a public jenkins instance and one of its builds in order to get "candidate_revision" parameter for "lastSuccessfulBuild" build:

https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/All/job/account-plugins-vivid-i386-ci/lastSuccessfulBuild/parameters/

https://jenkins.qa.ubuntu.com/view/All/job/account-plugins-vivid-i386-ci/lastSuccessfulBuild/api/xml?xpath=/freeStyleBuild/action/parameter[name=%22candidate_revision%22]/value

Comment: for pipeline (non-freestyle): `https://<JENKINS_DOMAIN_NAME>/job/<jobname>/<buildnum>/api/xml?xpath=/workflowRun/action/parameter\[name="<params_name>"\]/value`. Or get value directly: `curl -s 'https://<JENKINS_DOMAIN_NAME>/job/<jobname>/<buildnum>/api/xml?xpath=/workflowRun/action/parameter\[name="<params_name>"\]/value' | sed -re 's:<[^>]+>([^<]+)<.*$:\1:'`