# How to parse the xml output through Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, xml-parsing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have to hit a URL to get the test case results in Jenkins pipeline job, but this URL is giving me XML format output in console of Jenkins. Is there any solution to parse this XML output through Jenkins or any groovy language(I'm using scripted pipeline here). Need to send this parsed output to the Developers to convey the result case results.
Any plugin which can parse this XML?.

Comment: Please share jenkinsFile.

Comment: use the api concept in jenkins .... i have explained it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50837671/retrieve-parameter-from-a-jenkins-rest-query/50920289#50920289

Comment: Yeah, I will have look for the solution,Thank You.